# Ember Data TypeForRoot no longer being called

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

We are currently on Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.18, Ember 1.12 and CLI 0.2.7.

Since this last update, we are getting ember data assertion warnings like the following:

```
[Warning] WARNING: Encountered "open_requests" in payload, but no model was found for model name "open-request" (resolved model name using vault@serializer:appuser:.typeForRoot("open_requests")) (vendor.js, line 15423)
```

I also noticed that a console log we included in the appuser serializer is no longer called:

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend( {
    typeForRoot: function(root) {
        console.log('appuser serializer called', root);
        if (root === 'open_requests') return this._super('openrequest');
        return this._super(root);
    },
});
```

I can confirm that TypeForRoot was called prior to this update. We have had a number of other issues since upgrading and it seems that they could all be related in some way to the serializers, so the questions are why are we getting these warnings and why is typeForRoot no longer being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember Data switched to `modelNameFromPayloadKey`, `typeForRoot` is no longer used in the code unless you are specifically calling it.

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_typeForRoot

Comment: It is incorrect to say that `typeForRoot` was "deprecated". "Deprecated" would mean it still works, probably with a deprecation warning. In this case, `typeForRoot` was randomly replaced with a different name, with no warning or deprecation message whatsoever. This is sloppy. It would have been trivial to make the change so that it checked for a `typeForRoot` method and issued a deprecation message if it was there, and still call it. The way this was implemented your application just silently fails.

Answer (score 3):

beta.18 introduced a potentially breaking change - looks like it caused your app to break..

**Short answer:** rename `typeForRoot` to `modelNameFromPayloadKey`

#### From the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

[#3034] **POTENTIALLY BREAKING CHANGE** if you override `typeForRoot` currently introduce `modelNameFromPayloadKey` and deprecate `typeForRoot` @fivetanley

- `RESTSerializer#typeForRoot` has been deprecated. You can use `RESTSerializeer#modelNameFromPayloadKey` instead.
- Added `RESTSerializer#payloadKeyFromModelName`. This allows you to
- `typeKey` on Snapshots and Model classes has been deprecated. Use modelName instead. specify the outgoing root key for a JSON payload.

#### From the [Blog Post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/21/ember-data-1-0-beta-18-released.html)

**DS.RESTSERIALIZER.TYPEFORROOT IS NOW DS.RESTSERIALIZER.MODELNAMEFROMPAYLOADKEY**

To gain more consistency in the naming change of `typeKey` to `modelName`, `typeForRoot` has been renamed to `modelNameFromPayloadKey`. The function serves the same purpose, so this should be a quick refactor you can achieve via search and replace in your project. While calling typeForRoot will trigger a deprecation warning, overriding in a subclass won't.

Comment: *While calling typeForRoot will trigger a deprecation warning, overriding in a subclass won't.* Yet overriding in a subclass is far and away the most common use case.